# Creating button with specific geometry XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Please can anyone suggest a solution of my problem.
Most "custom buttons" on different tutorials based on standard geometry forms (triangle, rectangle, circle etc.) anв changed only their appearance.
I trying to create button with specific geometry and changed it on mouse event.
what I have:
I created style where diskribe
I created a polygon in the form of a rectangle with rounded corners (this is important)
I created style where described my custom button, and in main window i added the Style attribute:

```
<Button Width="40" Margin="5,0,5,-15" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="40" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PLCButtonStyle}"/>
```

this is how i described geometry:

```
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >      
                <Grid> 
                    <MAIN:RoundedCornersPolygon  Name="Border" Points="0,0 75,0 75,15 75,30 0,30 "Stretch="Fill"  
                        StrokeThickness="1" ArcRoundness="5" UseRoundnessPercentage="False" Stroke="Black" IsClosed="True
                        <MAIN:RoundedCornersPolygon.Fill>   
                                <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" GradientOrigin="0.7,0.3" >
                                    <GradientStop Color="lightgray" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="black" Offset="1" />
                                </RadialGradientBrush> 
                        </MAIN:RoundedCornersPolygon.Fill>              
                    </SCADA:RoundedCornersPolygon>
```

I need to animate the transition of certain points of the polygon from one coordinate to another.
from  Points="0,0 75,0 75,15 75,30 0,30 " 
to    Points="0,0 60,0 75,15 60,30 0,30 "
what i need to do for this?

Comment: You're probably going to need to Storyboard your animation, using EventTriggers to start and stop the Storyboards. Some useful info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx .

Comment: I looked very carefully at Storyboards, but did not find any function that is suitable for working with polygon. I need to change the position of the two coordinates(in this case)of five, not color, not size

Comment: There's a reasonable looking example of changing a shape's points using a PointAnimation here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8da09f24-56c1-4e3c-b3b9-5985c32f27d6/wpf-transformation?forum=wpf . Unfortunately, to make use of it you'd need to rejig your existing shape into a Path with a PathGeometry, and then individually name and animate each LineSegment within the PathGeometry. Bit of a kerfuffle.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Еhat's why I wanted to use the polygon.
(

Comment: Blend makes this pretty easy if you're familiar with using their storyboard timeline recording etc. Except Path geometry generally makes life easier like goobering pointed out.

Comment: I haven't checked your co-ordinates and don't know what shapes you're transitioning between - is the point of the exercise to transition from a rectangular button to a completely different shape, or are you just trying to animate a size change?

Comment: not the size and shape
From  |button| i need: |button>

Comment: Got it. I think you're stuck with Storyboard - was considering other possibilities, but they're all rectangle-based.